# How do I solve the 'Verification Human CAPTCHA Secret sign' on Opera Mini?

Tags: bug, login, captcha, opera-mini

I am trying to log in using Opera Mini.

How can I solve the 'Verification Human CAPTCHA Secret sign', since it doesn't pop up any button to click on?

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: Thanks for feedback me,
but problem Is Robot Button invisible,,

actually I'm using Mobile,

not show Robot button in my opera mini browser,

Comment: @Peter: In future, you may wish to either edit sooner or edit later to avoid wasting questions' sole auto-reopen chances on copyediting.

Answer (score 5):

Opera mini *is* a robot, since it downloads the page from the server and renders an [altered version of the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini) which is sent to your device. Thus it lacks being able to login, retain cookies, etc.

From the linked Wikipedia page:

> However, interactive sites which depend upon the device processing JavaScript do not work properly.

For this reason, Opera mini is not supported as browser for anything other than viewing.

Comment: But brother,
what's way?

Comment: I am not your brother as far as I know and I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: i means how solve way to my queation

Comment: @AbdulQaYooM As Patrick states - Opera Mini is not a supported browser. You will need to use a different browser.

Comment: Ok,

Thanks for feedback and support me,,

Comment: @PatrickHofman In many parts of the world, particularly the Islamic world, *brother* is used as a polite form of address for an adult man. Kinda like our *sir* or *mister*, as in *Sir, do you have the time?*, only without the connotations of an asymmetry in social class. Similar to *comrade* in the old 2nd world. When Catholicism was a stronger influence on the western world, *brother* itself was not uncommon here, either. I think the last vestige of this is the phrase *Brother, can you spare a dime?*.

Comment: @Dan well, in other parts it comes as a slang for "old time friend", e.g. "dude" - I'm pretty sure Patrick is well aware OP didn't mean brother in its literal form, but thought he was trying to address him as a close friend.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, that's how I read it as well, which is the expectation I was trying to dispel with my comment (admittedly, it was drawn from an assumption I made given OP's name).